# How can I treat certain patterns as web-site links, that can be followed with org-open-at-point?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

At work I frequently deal with support issues that my company keeps track of in a web-based bug tracker.

Each issue has an URL that looks like `https://mycompany.com/support/SUPPORT-12345`, but of course I don't want to spell this out every time I mention a support issue in my [Org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) file.  I would like set up Org-mode in such a way that the pattern `SUPPORT-(\d+)` is treated as a hyperlink to `https://mycompany.com/support/SUPPORT-\1`.

I would like to be able to place my cursor over the `SUPPORT-2345`, type `C-c C-o`, and have Emacs point my browser to `https://mycompany.com/support/SUPPORT-2345`.  Ideally, `SUPPORT-2345` would behave no different than a hyperlink.

Can Org-mode be configured in this way?  If not, what is the best alternative?

Comment: I would suggest asking this on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with `org-link-abbrev-alist`. For example, see the below for some I use. You can then put `[[Support:1234]]` in your Org-mode file and have it treated as the expanded link.

```
  (setq org-link-abbrev-alist
    '(
      ("DOI" . "http://dx.doi.org/")
      ("FreshDesk" . "https://xyz.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/")
      ("JIRA" . "https://jira.apps.monash.edu/browse/")
      ("Support" . "https://support.xyz.com/helpdesk/tickets/")
      ("ISBN" . "http://isbn.nu/")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Org-mode have this feature, but there is a `bug-reference-mode` for it.

Here is sample org file:

```
;; Local Variables:
;; eval: (bug-reference-mode)
;; bug-reference-bug-regexp: "\\(\\(?:\\(?:SUPPORT\\|support\\)-\\)\\([0-9]+\\)\\)"
;; bug-reference-url-format: "https://mycompany.com/support/SUPPORT-%s"
;; End:

* SUPPORT-123
* support-1234
```

And you can move point on support-* and press `C-c RET` (bug-reference-push-button) to open it.

[image]

For more detail about *Bug Reference*, please refer to `C-h r g Bug Reference`